# Find the value of input type text closest to checkbox using jquery

Tags: jquery

[Working code in JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/pVA36/)

I have put the complete code in `JSFiddle`, the problem is that it fetches the `val` of the first input box, but doesn't fetch the content where the `checkbox` is `checked`?

**Html**

```
<div class="gallery_content_wrap">
<!-- video wrap-->

<div class="gallery_photo_wrap">
  <div class="gallery_bg_wrap">
  <input type="hidden" value="10" name="selectypeaccept">
  <input type="hidden" value="photos" name="subadmintypeaccept">

        <div name="photosacceptdiv" class="gallery_bg"> <img width="200px" border="0" height="148px" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7180/6846918679_7891edd209_t.jpg">  
<br>   <input type="text" value="" id="phototitle">  <input type="checkbox" value="1d7457596c0f202ae373de1737bb0e4a.png" name="photosaccept">
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- video wrap-->

<div class="gallery_photo_wrap">
  <div class="gallery_bg_wrap">
  <input type="hidden" value="10" name="selectypeaccept">
  <input type="hidden" value="photos" name="subadmintypeaccept">

        <div name="photosacceptdiv" class="gallery_bg"> <img width="200px" border="0" height="148px" src="http://farm7.staticflickr.com/6186/6054843777_4e90c30827_t.jpg">  
<br>   <input type="text" value="" id="phototitle">  <input type="checkbox" value="3.png" name="photosaccept">
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- video wrap-->

<div class="gallery_photo_wrap">
  <div class="gallery_bg_wrap">
  <input type="hidden" value="10" name="selectypeaccept">
  <input type="hidden" value="photos" name="subadmintypeaccept">

        <div name="photosacceptdiv" class="gallery_bg"> <img width="200px" border="0" height="148px" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7021/6846957961_779518a6c5_t.jpg">  
<br>   <input type="text" value="" id="phototitle">  <input type="checkbox" value="9d0757dd339b0b1afa3aabe6b1a50cda.png" name="photosaccept">
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- video wrap-->    

<div class="gallery_photo_wrap">
  <div class="gallery_bg_wrap">
  <input type="hidden" value="10" name="selectypeaccept">
  <input type="hidden" value="photos" name="subadmintypeaccept">

        <div name="photosacceptdiv" class="gallery_bg"> <img width="200px" border="0" height="148px" src="http://farm8.staticflickr.com/7181/6858152461_91dd47bfc8_t.jpg">  
<br>   <input type="text" value="" id="phototitle">  <input type="checkbox" value="26a70bb20de5d595d2fde46abbc740f8.png" name="photosaccept">
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
<!-- video wrap-->            

</div><div align="center"><input type="submit" name="submitaccept" value="Approve"/><input type="submit" name="submitacceptreload" value="Reload"/>
</div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("[name=submitaccept]").click(function(){
    checktype();
});

function checktype(){
    $("[name=photosaccept]").each(function() {       
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $phototitle=$(this).val();
            alert($("#phototitle").val());
            $photoname = $("#phototitle").val();
        }
    });            
}​
```

Comment: Put the relevant code **in the question**. Why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118392/add-stack-overfow-faq-entry-or-similar-for-putting-code-in-the-question

Comment: They all have the same ID, and you are trying to get the value of that ID, so it only fetches the first one as it does not expect there to be any more ID's as it is supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace your `$.each` function with this

```
$("[type=checkbox]").each(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')){
        alert($(this).closest("div.gallery_bg").find("input[type=text]").val());
    }
});
```

and it should work.

But I must stress however, that you listen to what the guys above are saying, to prevent future errors from occurring.

Comment: @dude I can capture the text of any textbox that I check. here is a [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drewP/hrdDD/) of what i did.

Answer (score 0):

So many things wrong...
The `name` of each checkbox should be unique, or else you should put it as a group, `name="group[]"`. Same with `id`s, they should be unique, and you're using many `id="phototitle"`. That's probably why your code isn't working properly. Then you're doing this:

```
$photoname = $("[name=phototitle]").val();
```

When you want to do this:

```
$photoname = $("#phototitle").val();
```

Etc, etc... I'm afraid you'll probably need to rethink the whole thing.

Comment: how to call the name=group[] in js

Comment: ie. all checkboxes with `name = colors[]` will be in one group which you can then iterate through with php like `forEach(color in $_POST['colors'])`